# How to filter a collection with with another collection?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have two main collections:

- `groups`, which is keyed on auto-ids, and has `GroupID = (auto-id)`, `Creator` and `Groupname` fields.
- `users`, which is keyed on `uid`, and has a subcollection `usergroups` 
  which contains all `GroupIDs (auto-ids from the Groups collection)` that are assigned to the user.

Now I want to filter the `groups` collection with the `usergroups` collection.

The result should be that the user only sees the groups that are saved in his user profile.
[image]

[image]

My first attempt looks like this:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot>  userGroupIDs() async*{
    String docId;
     Stream<QuerySnapshot> snap = Firestore.instance.collection("users").document("uid").collection('usergroups').snapshots();
     await for(var snapData in snap){
       snapData.documents.forEach((docResult){
        docId =  docResult.documentID;
       });
     }
   yield* Firestore.instance.collection('groups').where('GroupID', isEqualTo: docId).snapshots();
  }
```

Then inside `StreamBuilder`:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                            stream: userGroupIDs(),
```

Comment: do you want to filter groups which is inside user collection ? in userGroups from while collection's GroupId do you want to use filter ?

Comment: Your setup looks promising already. You'll want to: 1) get a list of group IDs, instead of the single `docId` you now keep, and then: 2a) either pass that list to a [`whereIn` query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60046386), 2b) or perform a single-document lookup for each doc ID. Also see my somewhat related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59097364

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya 
It's hard for me to explain. I want  to match the documents ids in the "usergroups" with the documents who have the same id in the "groups" collection. 
Only the matching documents should be displayed in a listview. 
Sorry my english is not that good.